# how to set the Environmnet value in linux while executing dotnet test command

Tags: selenium-webdriver, .net-core

I am trying to execute dotnet test on docker( ubuntu 16.04) shell like "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=test1 dotnet test"

**Problem:** Environment parameter is not taken into account.

I have appsettings for every environment like appsetting.Debug.json,appsetting.test1.json,appsetting.test2.json etc

Whenever I am executing for any environment respective appsettings file is not referenced,I can see it is trying to contact localhost:4444/wd/hub which is mentioned in appsetting.Debug.json

appsetting.test1.json have different value for selenium hub

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the environment variable name. It should be `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#environments

Comment: sorry for typo . It was not working with correct name as well.